# Getting difference between two Timestamp objects in Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, timestamp

I'm working on a project, it's about parking and it contains a database. I have variable timestamp for time/date when car enter the parking, and one also for when the car is on the exit.
I want to get difference in hours (minute after every full hour is a new hour etc. 4 hours and 2 mins are same as 5 hours) so I can calculate price of the service (hours multiply by price per hour).

Help me pls, and thank you in advance

Comment: I was trying a lot of codesamples yesterday but all documentation I have found untill now is related to .time .gethours, I want to save date and time, and type is timestamp, ? I'm not sure is that the best way to do it?  (in sql and in java also)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get difference in milliseconds and calculate as below

```
long timeDiff = endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime()

int hours = (int)Math.ceil(timeDiff/1000*60*60) //In here we are converting milli seconds difference to hours and then if it is not an exact number we are converting that to the next integer
```

Comment: and what if date has changed? example. start time is 11pm and end time 1am ... I'm not really sure does it works with timestamps (date and time) :/

Comment: yes it does when you use getTime() method returns how many milliseconds have passed since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT

Comment: if you agree that the answer is correct please vote and accept the answer

Comment: yea sorry I'm slow I'm in middle of proggramming, I always do that ^^ thank you all vm

Answer (score 0):

After obtaining the time value in milliseconds (e.g. using a `Date` object) use `TimeUnit` to get the difference in times:

```
TimeUnit.HOURS.convert(timeOut.getTime()-timeIn.getTime(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Comment: I think I have a idea what to do now. thank you all for your time.. 
@suresh reddy guntaka and austin d